# how to validate two forms in one page using php? Each form redirects to same page

Tags: php, forms

this is my code i used for validating search form and i have two form in different tabs .Only one form will submitted at a time but due to validation it shows error

```
<?php
$foutcityErr = $toutcityErr = $dateoutErr = "";
$foutcity = $toutcity = $dateoutErr = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($_POST["foutcity"])) {
        $foutcityErr = "Please type source";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $foutcity= test_input($_POST["foutcity"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$foutcity)) {
            $foutcityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            $valid = false;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["toutcity"])) {
        $toutcityErr = "Please type destination";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $toutcity= test_input($_POST["toutcity"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$toutcity)) {
            $toutcityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            $valid = false;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["$dateoutErr"])) {
        $dateoutErr = "Please choose loading date";
        $valid = false;
    }
    else {
        $dateout= test_input($_POST["dateout"]);
    }
    if($valid){
        setcookie('foutcity',$foutcity);
        setcookie('toutcity',$toutcity);
        setcookie('dateout',$dateout);
        header('Location:resultout.php');
        exit();

    }
}
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}}?>
```

I'm using same validation method for both the form and one form will be submitted once.

Comment: So your question is "how can I know which form was submitted?" or something else?

Comment: Exactly and I a getting error while form submission.

Comment: Whenever I submit form It shows error undefined function

Comment: No line number in the error message?

Comment: You call `test_input(...)`, but where is it defined?

Comment: Please make understand how to validate two forms in one page using php and on submission of any of form redirect to another page.

Comment: I have defined the test_input(...) in my page

Comment: Yes, but inside an if block. That means it will not be known until the execution reaches that point. See my answer.

Comment: You have an unmatched `}` on the last line of the code. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Answer (score 0):

To know in your `PHP` code which form was submitted, in your first form, add:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="form_number" value="1"/>
```

and in your second form, add:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="form_number" value="2"/>
```

Then in your `PHP` code, after the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` test, do:

```
 if ($_POST["form_number"] == "1") {
     // your code for form 1
 } else {
     // your code for form 2
 }
```

You also have an error in your code: there are 11 opening braces, and 12 closing braces: this is not correct. Either you have not given all the code and the `test_input` function is defined in an `if { }` block:  then it does not exist until the code execution reaches that point. Move it out of the block.

Or you really have a closing brace too many at the end: remove it.

I would also improve a bit on the indenting of your code.

Comment: I fixed the indentation, now you can see that `test_input` is not inside the `if` block. for some reason it has an extra `}` after it, though.

Comment: Then you have one too many. You need as many opening as closing braces. You should correct it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, he has an unmatched `}`. I said the same thing in a comment above.

Comment: Did you think I was the OP?

Comment: Yes I thought you were :-) Thanks for fixing the indentation.

Comment: when i used your given code i get error as "Undefined index: form_number "

Comment: Could you share in your question the HTML code you generate for the  `form` tags? Did you put the two `input`s inside them?